# Jade/Pug img and text into link

Tags: html, pug

I want to make something like this:

```
<a href="tel:+380631234567">
    <img src="somePath" alt="">
    + 380631234567
</a>
```

This obviously won't work, because img is self closing tag:

```
a(href="tel:+380681234567"): img(src="somePath") +38 (068) 12 34 567
```

Is it possible to do this using Jade/Pug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this app https://html2pug.herokuapp.com/ you can do it like this:

```
a(href="tel:+380631234567")
  img(src="somePath" alt="")
  | + 380631234567
```

I also find it difficult to use `pug`, so tools like the one I linked to really helps. Just google for **html to pug converters** if you are looking for alternatives.

Comment: @neku894 happy to help